# I'm getting a really poor app uptime in the B1 plan

Tags: azure

Hey I just made two Linux web apps on azure (running the same code), one on the F1 service plan and one on the B1 service plan
Somehow I'm getting a better app uptime in the F1 service plan, why's that so and how do I fix this?

Comment: How do measure uptime, Application Insight health check or some other tools?

Comment: Based on this information there's not a lot we can do. Please provide a [mcve] and refer to [ask]. Provide us with enough information to help.

Comment: @Andriy Bilous I'm hosting a discord bot which has a command to monitor the uptime of the app

Comment: Could you please try to monitor your application using Application Insight URL ping test and compare results with discord bot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

Comment: I used a simple website monitor like uptimerobot for that. It shows a 100% uptime while my bot keeps restarting every 1 hour, im confused now.

Comment: even the availability in the azure portal gives a 100% result